# Calculate the number of intersections of the given lines

Tags: algorithm

I'm just preparing for Google's phone interview, and run into this question:

Given a list of lines in 2D space, how to calculate the number of intersections in less than O(n^2) time?

They say the interviewee gave out a O(n^2) solution and then the interviewer asked if he could work out a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: lines (just FYI I cannot guarantee the question is 100% correct, so if somebody knows there's no known better solution, that's also an answer)

Comment: If it's line segments, you can use the [Bentley-Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm), which runs in O((n + k) log n) time, for `n` lines and `k` intersections.  I think that's a fairly usually asked interview question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two lines in 2D either intersect once or they are parallel. If no lines are parallel, there are n*(n-1)/2 intersections. An O(n log n) solution is to sort lines by slope, then scan for parallelism, subtracting m*(m-1)/2 for each set of m parallel lines found.

Of course, this ignores any practical issues of floating point roundoff, but I'm assuming that this would have been mentioned in the question if it needed to be considered.

Comment: @agou - The question was how many intersections there were, not how many points of intersection. The latter is much more complicated. Since there are O(n^2) points of intersection, I don't think one could improve on the interviewee's answer.

Comment: OK, since I'm not sure about the question itself, your answer makes sense, I'll just wait a few more hours and see if there's better solution to the hard one.

Comment: thanks. Basically once you sort the slopes, then as you traverse through the sorted 'array' of slopes, for each pair of equal slopes found, decrement by 1. Isn't it.

Comment: @goldenmean - If `m` lines are parallel, then there are `m*(m-1)/2` pairs of equal slopes among them. (Or, put another way, `m*(m-1)/2` intersections avoided.) That's where that subtraction comes from.